# How do I create a list from an already existing list without the new list changing?

Tags: python, list, comparison

In this example:

```
m = [100, 33, 234, 5]
n = m
m.append(89)
print(n)
# Output: [100, 33, 234, 5, 89]
```

How do I make it so `n` doesn't contain 89?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is `[:]`, but note that this only applies to single-level arrays, if you need to deal with multi-level arrays (such as: `[[1,2],[3,4]]`), you need to use deepcopy

```py
m = [100, 33, 234, 5]
n = m[:]
m.append(89)
print(n)
# Output: [100, 33, 234, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the first list.

```
m = [100, 33, 234, 5]
n = m.copy()
m.append(89)
print(n)

# Output: [100, 33, 234, 5]
```